# CakePHP naming convention: explicit declaration required?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Lets take for example the documentation found in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Using entities `Recipe` and `Ingredient` and following the convention, in a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relationship, the join table would be called `ingredients_recipes`.

As far as I understand, the point of following the naming conventions is to let `cakePHP` do the auto wiring of classes without the need of explicitly declare some variables, in this case, the name of the table: `ingredients_recipes`

Now, in the following example (extracted directly from the link above), they **explicitly** declare `'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id'`, `'associationForeignKey' => 'ingredient_id'` and `'joinTable' => 'ingredients_recipes'`.

My question would be: even though I have followed the naming conventions for tables, foreign keys, etc. Do I have to explicitly declare the names for the join table, foreign key, etc. or are they declared in the example below just to show the reader a possible value to input there?

```
// Example extracted from the documentation
class Recipe extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Ingredient' =>
            array(
            'className' => 'Ingredient',
            'joinTable' => 'ingredients_recipes',
            'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
            )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have followed everything, you do not have to write that whole load of code, with a simple

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Ingredient');
```

you'll be fine. They give you that example to show you how much you can do with configuration, but unless you want to change any of the defaults set there, you're ok with the one-liner.